# Converting a string from a file into a date

Tags: date, string

I'm trying to read a string from a file and then convert it into a date but for some reason it's failing. I'm actually modifying a GeekTool Geeklet that's not working at the moment. It reads a file locally and pulls out a target date that is then used in a countdown clock.
The line of code that is failing is:

```
TARGET=$(date -j -f %D_%T $1 +%s)
```

I know that I can hardcode the value in the script using -v but I want to work out why this line isn't working. I can't seem to find any refs to converting a string from a file into a date object. I also can't find refs to -j or -f flags...

[edit]
Here's the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Homework countdown
# BETA - I will update this when I get more time
function countdown
{
CURRENT=$(date +%s)
TARGET=$(date -j -f %D_%T $1 +%s)
LEFT=$((TARGET-CURRENT))
WEEKS=$((LEFT/604800))
DAYS=$(( (LEFT%604800)/86400))
HOURS=$(( (LEFT%86400)/3600))
MINS=$(( (LEFT%3600)/60))
SECS=$((LEFT%60))

lblWEEKS="Weeks"
lblDAYS="Days"

if [ $DAYS == 1 ]
then
lblDAYS="Day"
fi

if [ $WEEKS == 1 ]
then
lblWEEKS="Week"
fi

if [ $HOURS -lt 10 ]
then
    HOURS=0$HOURS
fi  

if [ $MINS -lt 10 ]
then
    MINS=0$MINS
fi


if [ $SECS -lt 10 ]
then
    SECS=0$SECS
fi

echo $1
echo $TARGET
echo $2 $WEEKS Weeks, $DAYS $lblDAYS $HOURS:$MINS:$SECS
# Optional extra line between timers
echo
}
DATES=( $( cat /Users/Shared/Deadlines.txt ) )
# Even numbered indices are names, odd numbered indices are dates


if [ ${#DATES[@]} == 0 ]
then
echo "No Deadlines!"
return
fi

for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#DATES[@]} ; i+=2 ))
do
countdown ${DATES[i+1]} ${DATES[i]}
done
```

And the file simply contains:
    test: 17/05/2011_12:00

Comment: Why don't you show the pertinent content of the file and the desired output? `-j` is not present in `GNU date`, what `date` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the script was written for [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=date&sektion=1).

> `-f input_fmt`: Use `input_fmt` as the format string to parse the new_date provided rather than using the default `[[[[[cc]yy]mm]dd]HH]MM[.ss]` format. Parsing is done using `strptime(3)`.
>   `-j`: Do not try to set the date.  This allows you to use the `-f` flag in addition to the `+` option to convert one date format to another.

These are nonstandard extensions to the [standard `date`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/date.html) command, which can only format the current date. Under Linux (or Cygwin) or any other system with GNU date, you can use the `-d` option if you're willing to pass a different date format:

```
TARGET=$(date -d "$1" +%s)
```

and call the script as e.g. `test 2011/05/17 12:00`. For fancier parsing, preprocess the string in the shell first or call Perl or Python:

```
TARGET=$(IFS=/_:; set $1; date +%S $(($2*10000000000+$1*100000000+
                                      $4*1000000+$5*10000+$1)))
TARGET=$(perl -l -e '($day,$month,$year,$h,$m) = split(/[^0-9]+/, $ARGV[0]); print mktime(0, $m, $h, $day, $month, $year-1900)' "$1")
TARGET=$(python -c '
    import sys, time;
    print time.strftime("%s", time.strptime(sys.argv[1], "%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M"))
   '            "$1")
```